# implementing flashcards in Kivy (problem with fixed height of cards)

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivymd, kivy-recycleview

I'm trying to create a UI in *kivy* where users get to set answer to flashcards in a message like format. I've got the following code, which works (in terms of functionality), but I'm stuck with the cards not resizing properly (height of card)

- ui.kv

```
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "Name of the course"
        elevation: 4
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        md_bg_color: "#424242"
        specific_text_color: "#F2F2F2"
        right_action_items: 
            [["arrow-left", lambda x: app.callback(x), "Go back"],
            ["pencil", lambda x: app.edit_callback(x), "Rename course"],
            ["delete", lambda x: app.delete_callback(x), "Delete course"]]
        
    MDRecycleView:
        id: card_rv
        viewclass: 'FlashCard'
        
        RecycleBoxLayout:

            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1, None
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.minimum_height
            padding: dp(8)
            spacing: dp(16)
            


    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: dp(54)

        MDTextField:
            size_hint_min_x: 0.8
            id: input_field
            multiline: True
            hint_text: 'Enter your answer...'

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: 'Send'
            on_release: root.send_answer()
```

- flashCard.kv

```
<FlashCard>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
       
    MDLabel:
        text: root.question
        halign: "left"
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        text_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        text_size: self.width, None
        md_bg_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
        height: self.texture_size[1]


    MDLabel:
        text: root.answer
        halign: "right"
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        text_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        text_size: self.width, None
        md_bg_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
        height: self.texture_size[1]
```

- append_flash.py

```
...
for card in self.cards:
    card = card.to_dict()
    self.ids["card_rv"].data.append(card)
    self.ids["card_rv"].refresh_from_data()
...
```

Now when I try to load the cards with some lorem ipsum text, the underlying box (card) does not adjust height as desired and the text overflows:
[image: box is not adjusting height to capture whole text]

I tried using MDBoxLayout with `adaptive_height: True` in `<FlashCard>:` widget, but had no success.

Comment: Could you please provide the Python script to run the code so we can try to see where the problem lies?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a ScrollView rather than a RecycleView.  If the widgets in a RecycleView are going to have different sizes, you need to use the key_size attribute of the RecycleLayout: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recyclelayout.html#kivy.uix.recyclelayout.RecycleLayout.key_size

If you have a performance issue with ScrollView, you can invest in making the changes to create a RecycleView.

Comment: Thank you, got it working with scroll view in the end (appending widgets/cards to the box layout that is nested inside the scroll view).